# web3.eth.getAccounts() never give any output

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment

```
const deploy = async () => {  
    **var acct = await web3.eth.getAccounts();**  
    console.log("ac", acct);  
}    
deploy();
```

even the console is not getting printed,what could be the reason?
any possible solution would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

From new updates, now you have to request access of accounts by using method `await ethereum.enable();` before `getAccounts`.For, more details check : [this](https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8)

Comment: thanks for the information it cleared my most of the doubts,but i am not getting   the part how can i use **'window'** variable in  the code since it is part of the   browser.  
i am getting the error as window is not defined.

Comment: window.web3 only injected by metamask when you are viewing the page with HTTP and https protocol. So if you are viewing the page as a blank page or local page(file://), their won't be a web3 object in window scope.

Comment: I am not getting the above suggested solution.I have enabled privacy mode in metamask so how can i integrate it with the below code to get the accounts.

below is my code 

const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');  
const mnemonic = 'paraphrase'  
const web3 = new Web3(new HDWalletProvider(  
    mnemonic,  
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/'mytoken',  
));  
const deploy = async () => {  
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();  
    console.log("accounts", accounts);  
}  
deploy();

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `https` when calling your web3 provider. The code should be something like this:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const infuraKey = '*your_key*';
const mnemonic = '*your_passphrase*';

const web3 = new Web3(new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${infuraKey}`)); 

const deploy = async () => { 
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts(); 
    console.log("accounts", accounts); 
} 

deploy();
```